# Send cookie over HTTP on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, session-cookies

I have an express server hosting the static files and the API of my application. When the API tries to send a cookie on response Chrome shows the following warning:

> This attempt to set a cookie was blocked because it was not send over a secure connection and would have overwritten a cookie with the secure attribute.

Is there a way to overcome this? I don't really want to buy an SSL certificate for this domain because it is just a showoff project.

Comment: SSL/TSL certificates are free these days.

Comment: Really? Are you talking about self-signed certificates? or where can I get one for free?

Comment: Google 'Lets Encrypt', but this is also built into many hosting providers. It's over 5 years ago TSL certificates cost money =)